# ngfor let var of vars --> iterate through the full array + 1

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm learning angular2 and I found something odd.
I have a list of messages and I want to iterate through the full list to display my message in an other component :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-message-list',
  template: `<ul><my-message *ngFor="let message of messages" [message]="message"> </my-message></ul>`,
})
export class ListMessages  {
  messages :Array<Object>
  constructor(){
    this.messages = [] ;
    //this.messages.push({text:'zerg'});
    this.messages.push({text:'lolz1'});
    this.messages.push({text:'lolz2'});
    this.messages.push({text:'lolz3'});
    this.messages.push({text:'lolz4'});

  }

}
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-message',
  template: `<li >{{ message.text }}</li>`,
})
export class Message  {
  @Input() message:{text:string}
  constructor(){
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    if(typeof this.message === 'undefined'){
      this.message = {text:'o_O'};
    }

    debugger;
  }
}
```

With my debugger I noticed that on the first iteration everything is going fine. 
I have a :

```
<ul><!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
}--><my-message ng-reflect-message="[object Object]" ng-version="2.4.10"><li>lolz1</li></my-message><my-message ng-reflect-message="[object Object]"><li>lolz2</li></my-message><my-message ng-reflect-message="[object Object]"><li>lolz3</li></my-message><my-message ng-reflect-message="[object Object]"><li>lolz4</li></my-message></ul>
```

But after this iteration it'll go one more time with `undefined` and replace the first item with o_O

```
<ul><!--template bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
 }--><my-message ng-reflect-message="[object Object]" ng-version="2.4.10"><li>o_O</li></my-message><my-message ng-reflect-message="[object Object]"><li>lolz2</li></my-message><my-message ng-reflect-message="[object Object]"><li>lolz3</li></my-message><my-message ng-reflect-message="[object Object]"><li>lolz4</li></my-message></ul>
```

So it's not working but Why ?

Comment: Looks fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/pcwXHXGIMHOC9TQrGEz7?p=preview

Comment: Thank you a lot. This one doesn't : http://plnkr.co/edit/3E1lyrC3M6zPI6iBNgRQ?p=preview  I don't get why....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are also bootstrapping `Message` component in your `@NgModule`

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ ListMessages,Message ],
  bootstrap:    [ ListMessages,Message ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

remove it and update it like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ ListMessages,Message ],
  bootstrap:    [ ListMessages]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You are the real MVP <3.

Comment: @Su4p Haha glad I could help :-)